# Does the webbrowser require IE installed on client machine

Tags: c#, winforms, internet-explorer, browser

I was just wondering whether any version of I.E. must be installed on the client machine when deploying an application that uses the webbrowser control (target .net 2 platform)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the webbrower control uses `mshtml.dll` which is provided by Internet Explorer.

Comment: As the most up-voted answer states, removing IE does not remove MSHTML, so this answer should be, "No, the webbrowser control uses mshtml.dll, which is also used by Internet Explorer, but remains installed even if IE is removed".

Answer (score 3):

When you use the "Add/Remove Windows Components" applet to "remove" Internet Explorer, it removes the iexplore.exe entry point but leaves all of the components of the Web Browser Control installed. Those components are a critical part of windows and cannot be uninstalled.

Having said that, if the user does remove Internet Explorer using this option, there can be problems with Web Browser Controls that try to spawn new windows. Please see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/06/19/making-the-web-browser-control-launch-the-default-browser.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does - but every windows computer has IE preinstalled.

Answer (score -1):

The `webbrowser` control do require `IE present` on the machine as it requires `MSHTML`.