# .NET WebBrowserControl fallback

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, webbrowser-control

I'm using the.NET WebBrowserControl in one of my WinForms applications. Unfortunately some of the users have uninstalled the Microsoft IE, so that my applications crashes. Is there a known fallback solution?

I don't want to use another browser control like Awesomium, Chromium, Webkit, etc. - I only wan't to "try-catch" the application crashes, which occure, when a user hasn't a valid IE installtion.

Comment: you may want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746393/does-the-webbrowser-require-ie-installed-on-client-machine for a similar problem