# Can C#'s WPF WebBrowser control be used on machines without Internet Explorer installed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, internet-explorer

In 2009, Microsoft released a version of Windows 7 called "Windows 7 E" in Europe, which shipped with no web browser installed, due to some anti-trust lawsuits they were facing at the time.

Will the `WebBrowser` control in C# work on these machines? I would assume that everything required to get it to run would be included in the .NET framework, but I would like to make sure.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will, lots of Win7 system UI components use MSHTML and WebBrowser ActiveX controls. Can't be 100% sure though but you can easily verify that by firing a VM using "Windows 7 E" distributive from MSDN subscription.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6746393/does-the-webbrowser-require-ie-installed-on-client-machine